# How do I separate my text in the heading?

Tags: html, css

I want to separate the text styling from my header and body. How can I achieve this? I also want to keep the text in the heading inside my hero/background. I also need to add the appropriate media queries or flex's I assume? I am new to coding so please be weary that I am unfamiliar with all the terminology and coding elements. I am in coding bootcamp. I appreciate your help and tips.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Header Start */
#vanta-canvas {
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
}

.inner_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
}

.flex {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-content: normal;
}

.highlight {
color: blue;
font-family: cursive;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: cursive;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 45% 3px; 
    color: #b4b4b4;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover, button:focus{
    background-color: grey;
    color: blue;
}

button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

button:hover span:after{
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
/* Header End */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en_US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" > 
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="vanta-canvas">
            <header>
                <h1 class="inner_header" class="flex">
                     Hello, I'm&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="highlight">Brian Mojica.</span> 
                    <br>
                    I'm a full-stack web develop.
                </h1>
                <button class="flex" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>
                    View My Work
                </span></button>
            </header>
        
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r121/three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanta@latest/dist/vanta.waves.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                VANTA.WAVES({
                 el: "#vanta-canvas",
                mouseControls: true,
                 touchControls: true,
                gyroControls: false,
                minHeight: 100.00,
                minWidth: 100.00,
                scale: 1.00,
                scaleMobile: 1.00,
                color: 0x102
                 })
            </script>
        </div>

       <nav>
           Test
       </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a line divider, you can use the `<hr>` tag. 
There are different style attributes you can add, too.

```
<hr class="dashed">
<hr class="dotted">
<hr class="solid">
<hr class="rounded">
```

I hope this helps.

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't read your question close enough. 
You can add

```
header {
(css)
}
```

Just like you have

```
body {
(css)
}
```